# replay bash session with correct time delay

Tags: linux, bash

EDIT ( as it seems important, this goes on top, see below for details) : 
I need the script to actually execute the commands, not just display what was recorded ! script utility does not do this as far as I know. So something like auto hotkey, only for bash and linux, with timing information recorded.

The question was :

I would like to record and replay a bash session, with exact time delay between key presses and so on.

For instance, if I run a program called `xxx` and then break it with Ctrl+C after 11.4s and then run a program called `yyy` 3.4s after I exited `xxx`, I would like the replay to do the same (break `xxx` with Ctrl+C after 11.4s, wait 3.4s and then run `yyy`).

I don't need to record mouse movements, as all I am interested in recording happens in a single bash session.

I have looked into utilities as

- script (It records bash session commands, but no time delay info.)
- xmacro (It records all key presses but again no time info.)
- a person searching for something similar might also want to look [this](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/programming-scripting/105579-need-tool-record-keystrokes-replay-them.html) up
  (I am including this link because of possible value for other users;
  I personally don't find any of the solutions mentioned useful for
  what I want to achieve.)

Comment: I notice the Linux version of `script` has a `-t` option to record time. (The BSD version doesn't appear to have this, at least on my machine.) With the time, you can run [scriptreplay](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scriptreplay).

Comment: For clarification, do you want the time delay between key presses or the time delay between commands?

Answer (score 2):

script -t is the standard answer.

I also rewrote script in Python, which you can find here:
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/pypty/

Both support -t.  The main reason I wrote pypty was I wanted to be able to get one file per day for logging long ssh sessions, for the sake of future reference.

The pypty tarball includes a script-replay script (note slight difference of name from scriptreplay) that can go forward and back in a tty log file, using gtk or curses.  Its means of going backwards is a bit of a hack (because vt100 isn't that simple), but I've found it quite useful on a number of occasions.

Comment: Thank you ! As I feel I have searched through half of the internet before I posted this, I guess I should re-think my searching strategies (DFS is not the answer https://xkcd.com/761) 
And also thank you for the python reference. I was thinking about trying to write that kind of a program if I couldn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: Sory, I didn't notice that the script does not execute the commands.

Answer (score 1):

How about writing a bash wrapper in a language of your choosing which can log the information you need while providing access to the normal bash environment and pointing system settings towards your wrapper instead of the original bash?  IO would be piped between the client service/user and the real bash while your wrapper sits between logging the information you require.  The replay portion is trivial once the information has been logged.  I can provide examples upon request if you are interested in this approach.

Comment: Could you provide such examples ?
I can code in Python, c++, c, bash, so something familiar to me would be great.

Comment: Sure.  I'll throw something together and post back here with a link to the source.  PM me if you don't see an update here in a reasonable amount of time.